# EBAY API: findItemsAdvanced How do search by keyword and category?

Tags: html, json, ebay-api, ebay-lms

Been looking at the EBAY api tutorial

http://developer.ebay.com/DevZone/finding/HowTo/GettingStarted_JS_NV_JSON/GettingStarted_JS_NV_JSON.html

But I want to know how I can search according to category and keywords. I do this by using the operation `findItemsAdvanced`, but I don't really know what do here.  I have been trying to make it work but what i get back is an empty page. Here's the html:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>eBay Search Results</title>
<style type="text/css">body { font-family: arial,sans-serif;} </style>
</head>
<body>
<h1>eBay Search Results</h1>
<div id="results"></div>
<script>
//Parse the response and build an HTML table to display search results
function _cb_findItemsAdvanced(root) {

      var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];
      var html = [];
      html.push('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="3"><tbody>');
      for (var i = 0; i < items.length; ++i) {
        var item     = items[i];
        var title    = item.title;
        var pic      = item.galleryURL;
        var viewitem = item.viewItemURL;
        var price    = item.sellingStatus[0].currentPrice[0].__value__;

        if (null != title && null != viewitem) {
          html.push('<tr><td>' + '<img src="' + pic + '" border="0">' + '</td>' +
          '<td><a href="' + viewitem + '" target="_blank">' + title + '</a></td>'+ '<td>' + price + "$" + '</td></tr>');
        }
      }
      html.push('</tbody></table>');
      document.getElementById("results").innerHTML = html.join("");

}  // End _cb_findItemsByKeywords() function
//Construct the request
//Replace MyAppID with your Production AppID
var url = "http://svcs.ebay.com/services/search/FindingService/v1";
 url += "?OPERATION-NAME=findItemsAdvanced";
 url += "&SERVICE-VERSION=1.0.0";
 url += "&SECURITY-APPNAME=AppID";
 url += "&GLOBAL-ID=EBAY-US";
 url += "&RESPONSE-DATA-FORMAT=JSON";
 url += "&callback=_cb_findItemsAdvanced";
 url += "&REST-PAYLOAD";
 url += "&categoryId=1"; // video game  
 url += "&keywords=digimon%20world%201"; // change value to game title 
 url += "&paginationInput.entriesPerPage=6"; 

//Submit the request
 s=document.createElement('script'); // create script element
 s.src= url;
 document.body.appendChild(s);
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are two slight errors in your code.

The first is the categoryId - in your example you're specifying `categoryId=1`. For video games on the US eBay site this should be `categoryId=139973`. This should then give you results in your API call.

The second problem is when you come to parse the API call on line 13:

`var items = root.findItemsByKeywordsResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];`

Your code is looking for a `findItemsByKeywordsResponse` but your API call is a `findItemsAdvanced` - therefore you need to change the line in your Javascript function to:

`var items = root.findItemsAdvancedResponse[0].searchResult[0].item || [];`

I've just tested this and it works perfectly!

Comment: How did u get the categoryId for video games? Couldn't find it in anyway, may be i missed something from the API...

Comment: eBay categoryId's can be found here:
[link](http://listings.ebay.co.uk/_W0QQloctZShowCatIdsQQsacatZQ2d1QQsalocationZlicQQsocmdZListingCategoryList)

(Replace .co.uk with the correct country domain)

There is also a downloadable spreadsheet of all catID's available here:
[link](http://www.cgmlab.com/ebay-category-tree-download/)
which is automatically updated weekly.